# SharePoint Map drive error in windows

Tags: sharepoint-online, alternate-access-mapping, windows

Hope you're well;

We have had a lot of staff today with the error below.  They restarted their PC’s last night and they cannot connect to the drive.  I have disconnected and the remapped about 12 peoples drives so far and will need to do the remaining ones shortly.  Can this be fixed as we won’t be able to remap the drives manually for all staff each day.

[image]

Comment: Have the root cause why you had to re-map the drives been identified. I have lots of SP libraries mapped and haven't hit that problem before. I only had to remap the after OS update as they have not been properly migrated.

Comment: To avoid manual remapping consider using PowerSHell script to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to map the drives permanently and would consider a commercial solution you could try [Zee Drive for mapping network drives to OneDrive for Business and SharePoint Online](http://www.thinkscape.com/Map-Network-Drives-To-Office-365-OneDrive/).

Zee Drive will map the drives you configure when a user signs in to their computer and will ensure the drives are permanently mapped. Zee Drive also provides other benefits such as a File Explorer context menu to share files, access the recycle bin and quickly search for files.

Disclosure: I work for the company that develops Zee Drive.

Myles

Answer (score 0):

Map SharePoint with file drive
Open “Windows Explorer” from your server.
Right-click on the “Computer” icon, and select “Map network drive..”
Click “connect to a website that you can use to store your documents and pictures”
Give it a name.
Follow the instructor and finish!

This May Work,
Peter